# How to get messages from subfolders using JavaMail?

Tags: java, outlook, jakarta-mail

I am using JavaMail API to connect to outlook and read messages. I have list of sub folders under INBOX in my outlook account. I am able to get all messages from Inbox using:

```
Store store = session.getStore("imaps");
store.connect("outlook.office365.com", 993, MY_MAIL, MY_PASS);
Folder inbox = store.getFolder("Inbox");
```

But i am not able to read messages from sub folders. To read messages from a sub folder called `'subFolder'` i have tried:

```
Folder subFolder = store.getFolder("subFolder");
Folder subFolder = store.getFolder("Inbox\subFolder");
Folder subFolder = store.getFolder("Inbox.subFolder");
```

I am getting a FolderNotFoundException

```
javax.mail.FolderNotFoundException: Inbox.subFolder not found
    at com.sun.mail.imap.IMAPFolder.checkExists(IMAPFolder.java:452)
    at com.sun.mail.imap.IMAPFolder.open(IMAPFolder.java:1040)
    at com.sun.mail.imap.IMAPFolder.open(IMAPFolder.java:973)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `IMAPFolder` API Documentation says there is a method getFolder() on the Folder. Once you get the Inbox folder, call `getFolder()` on this folder passing the subfolder name.

Here is the reference https://eclipse-ee4j.github.io/javamail/docs/api/com/sun/mail/imap/IMAPFolder.html

Comment: Escaping the backslash doesn't help either. Still same exception.

Comment: It is under inbox.

Comment: Try using forward slash 'Inbox/subFolder'

Comment: IMAPFolder API Documentation says there is method 'getFolder()' on the Folder.<br>  Once you get the Inbox folder, call getFolder() on this folder passing subfolder name. Here is the reference https://javaee.github.io/javamail/docs/api/com/sun/mail/imap/IMAPFolder.html

Comment: Thank you very much for your hint. Very unintuitive, at least for me, but i got it working with : `Folder subFolder = store.getFolder("Inbox").getFolder("subFolder");` Please edit your answer accordingly so i can accept it. Thanks.

Comment: `store.getFolder("Inbox/subFolder")` should've worked too.

Comment: @BillShannon The OP tried `getFolder("Inbox\subFolder")` (backslash, not forward slash; and I'm assuming he actually tried `getFolder("Inbox\\subFolder")`)

Comment: @MarkRotteveel  Forward slash and backslash are not the same thing.  I have no idea whether the IMAP server he's using treats them as the same thing.

Comment: Folder subFolder = store.getFolder("Inbox").getFolder("subFolder");  This code helps me. Thanks

Comment: Don't you have to close the parent `Inbox` folder too? It *does* work for me to get the subfolder in one `store.getFolder("Test/Test")`, using IMAP at Office 365. Then again, the separator char (`store.getDefaultFolder().getSeparator()`) is `/`.

Comment: The link is broken (and the suggested edit queue is full). You can use instead https://javaee.github.io/javamail/docs/api/com/sun/mail/imap/IMAPFolder.html

Answer (score 1):

You probably use a wrong IMAP folder separator. The IMAP folder separator is not standardized and can be determined like this:

```
char separator = store.getDefaultFolder().getSeparator();
```

The most common separators are "." and "/". I guess that that "/" was the right choice in your case. `store.getFolder()` is able to access nested subfolders:

```
// assuming that "/" is the right separator
Folder folder = store.getFolder("inbox/subfolder");
```